# My metabox data are not saving

Tags: wordpress, attachment, meta-boxes

I am facing a problem which start to drive me nuts.I have created a metabox for my wordpress site. For the testings, I used it on a page. Everything went fine, without problems, but when I try to use the very same metabox in the media file (attachment) I am not able to save the datas. The metabox is properly displayed there, but I am unable to save any datas I enter in.
I must be missing something but can't figure out what.
Thanks in advance for your help
Kind regards
Alain

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$meta_box = array(
'id' => 'onzeroadagain-meta-box',
'title' => 'Prints size and price availablility',
'page' =>  'attachment',
'context' => 'normal',
'priority' => 'high',
'fields' => array(
    array(
        'name' => 'Small',
        'id' => 'small-checkbox',
        'type' => 'checkbox'
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Dimensions',
        'id' => 'dimension-small',
        'type' => 'text',
        'std' => 'W x H in cm'
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Price',
        'id' => 'price-small',
        'type' => 'text',
        'std' => 'in Euro'
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Medium',
        'id' => 'medium-checkbox',
        'type' => 'checkbox'
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Dimensions',
        'id' => 'dimension-medium',
        'type' => 'text',
        'std' => 'W x H in cm'
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Price',
        'id' => 'price-medium',
        'type' => 'text',
        'std' => 'in Euro'
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Large',
        'id' => 'large-checkbox',
        'type' => 'checkbox'
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Dimensions',
        'id' => 'dimension-large',
        'type' => 'text',
        'std' => 'W x H in cm'
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Price',
        'id' => 'price-large',
        'type' => 'text',
        'std' => 'in Euro'
    )    
)
);
add_action('admin_menu', 'onzeroadagain_add_box');
// Add meta box
function onzeroadagain_add_box() {
global $meta_box;
add_meta_box($meta_box['id'], $meta_box['title'], 'onzeroadagain_show_box', $meta_box['page'], $meta_box['context'], $meta_box['priority']);
}
// Callback function to show fields in meta box
function onzeroadagain_show_box() {
global $meta_box, $post;
// Use nonce for verification
echo '<input type="hidden" name="onzeroadagain_meta_box_nonce" value="', wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)), '" />';
echo '<table class="form-table">';
foreach ($meta_box['fields'] as $field) {
    // get current post meta data
    $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);
    echo '<tr>',
            '<th style="width:20%"><label for="', $field['id'], '">',   $field['name'], '</label></th>',
            '<td>';
    switch ($field['type']) {
        case 'checkbox':
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '"', $meta ? ' checked="checked"' : '', ' />';
            break;
        case 'text':
        echo '<input type="text" name="', $field['id'], '" id="',    $field['id'], '" value="', $meta ? $meta : $field['std'], '" size="30"   style="width:30%" />', '<br />', $field['desc'];
            break;
    }
    echo     '</td><td>',
        '</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
}
add_action('save_post', 'onzeroadagain_save_data');
// Save data from meta box
function onzeroadagain_save_data($post_id) {
global $meta_box;
// verify nonce
if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['onzeroadagain_meta_box_nonce'],     basename(__FILE__))) {
    return $post_id;
}
// check autosave
if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
    return $post_id;
}
// check permissions
if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {
    if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id)) {
        return $post_id;
    }
} elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
    return $post_id;
}
foreach ($meta_box['fields'] as $field) {
    $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);
    $new = $_POST[$field['id']];
    if ($new && $new != $old) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);
    } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {
        delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem lately. I had two different sets of metaboxes, one on the side and one on the 'normal' column. The fields in my 'side' metaboxes were saving fine but not the ones in 'normal'. I tried changing the context of my second one to 'side' instead of 'normal' and BAM! Everything saved fine.

So I suggest you try that too and tell us if it works.

I did some research but I found no explanation to this. There might be something I don't undestand and do the wrong way, or could be some kind of bug. I'll keep investigating.

Answer (score 0):

Hi modify your code like below:

```
add_action('save_post', 'onzeroadagain_save_data');
add_action( 'edit_attachment', 'onzeroadagain_save_data' );
```

The Key is:
**'edit_attachment'**